# Add security realm role using WLST

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I have started my WL Admin console. I went to the Security Realms -> myrealm -> Roles and Policies -> Global Roles -> Roles.
There I clicked on "New" button, created a new role, then modified it, giving it "Allow access to everyone" Role condition. Everything works perfectly.

My question is: how can I do just the same thing using WLST? I have managed to find these roles, to list them, to remove them, but I can't find any method to create a new role and to give it a role condition.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can start with this code sample : 
Role creation : 
`rm=cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().lookupRoleMapper("XACMLRoleMapper")
rm.createRole(None,"TestRole2",None,"")`

To create your condition, start reading this documentation : 
[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/secwlres/xacmlusing.html](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/secwlres/xacmlusing.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This definitely helped me!
To add the "Allow access to everyone" I needed to add the line:
rm.setRoleExpression(None,"TestRole2","?weblogic.entitlement.rules.UncheckedPolicy()")